# OBIEE Create Agent doesn't appear in menu

Tags: obiee

I wanted to create an agent to set up a mail trigger but I can't see 'agent' under my 'New' menu. I guess something is wrong with my privileges but I can't seem to figure out which ones I need to enable to create an agent. Can anyone help me here?

Thanks!

Here's a screenshot of my menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjate.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've found the answer ourselves: the View Delivers Full UX privilege needs to be on BI Content Author. Hope this can help others as well!